# How to resize a device local VkBuffer?

Tags: vulkan

Assume a host visible AND also device local VkDeviceMemory that is bound to a VkBuffer, acting as a vertex buffer. The bidirectional access properties of the memory makes it possible to "manipulate" the initial set of associated vertices post-initilization by simply memcpy'ing over the memory - that's fine. I like that.

But I am really confused on what would be "the flow" of practically resizing the vertex buffer? Let's apply it to a chunk of voxel terrain - to give a context: You destroy some terrain, resulting in less vertices than before. So what then?

Do you have to recreate the VkBuffer with a new size? That would screw up the binding in the render pass, wouldn't it? Do you have to re-record the whole command buffer then? Can you still use the same VkDeviceMemory? Do you have to reallocate the memory? It's... idk. I just need some direction of the broader concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you have to recreate the VkBuffer with a new size?

Vulkan splits resource access from the underlying memory allocation.

In terms of performance, reallocating memory is expensive but creating new buffer/buffer views is really just metadata and expected to be relatively inexpensive. For dynamic resources the usual approach is to over-allocate memory to "a large size" and then just reference the range of memory that is actively used by the current content.

If you must create a new version of a buffer and/or allocation you need to keep the old one "alive" until any pending commands referencing it have completed.

> That would screw up the binding in the render pass, wouldn't it?

If you are submitting an existing pre-recorded command buffer, then yes, the bindings are part of the recorded command buffer and will need regenerating.

If you are worried about existing bindings in the command buffer that is currently being recorded, then you need to ensure that the already recorded stay valid if you submit the commands. Allocate a new buffer/memory range for the new buffer, but don't reuse/deallocate the buffer memory that earlier queued commands are referencing. Wait for them to complete first, and then free the existing buffer.

> Do you have to re-record the whole command buffer then?

Pre-recorded buffers referring to old bindings will need to be re-recoded.

You don't need to re-record the start of the current command recording, just make sure the "old" buffer and memory stay alive until the queue submit completes.

Comment: [1/2] That's strange. I worked along the ol' vulkan-tutorial.com (https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Vertex_buffers/Vertex_buffer_creation). Here the binding of the vertex buffer happend during command buffer creation (more specifically during recording of the render pass) via a call to vkCmdBindVertexBuffer. The uniform and texture buffer however were in fact referenced during descriptor set creation.

Comment: [2/2] So I'm not sure you can call vkCmdBindVertexBuffer outside command buffer creation - hence the prefix vkCmd. I'm not expecting you to write down code, but can you reference any web ressource, any sample/tutorial that follows this approach? Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Correct, but unless you are rendering a static scene you are going to be recreating command buffers every frame anyway.

Comment: Not sure I can agree just yet. Currently I'm facing static content, but not necessarily a static scene. I can move around, turn the camera, move the vertices just fine - the command buffer is only created once (except for when the recreation of the swap chain is happening). So but you agree now that the vertex buffer binding is the responsibility of a command buffer creation, not the descriptor set - have I understood this correctly?

Comment: Yes, sorry - there are two cases and the generic answer depends on which one. 

For vertex buffers, this is though commands. For uniform buffers or other types of buffer you might resize it's through the descriptor set. If you're resizing mid-frame and creating a new patched descriptor set, that also needs a command to change the descriptor set binding, so it's not that different in practice.

Comment: In practice, pre-recording command buffers is something you almost never do; it's very cost-ineffective in terms of engineering cost, and no _that_ cost-effective in terms of runtime cost either; Vulkan command buffer recording is expected to be pretty efficient already.